# What is the difference between lxcbr0 and docker0 bridges?

Tags: docker, qnap

**What is the difference between `lxcbr0` and `docker0` bridges?**

"The lxcbr0 bridge provides Internet connectivity for containers in Container Station."

"The docker0 bridge provides Internet connectivity for containers of dependent applications."

Can I set them to the same IP 10.0.2.1/24?

In QNAP's Container Station, there are two bridge network settings.

[image: QNAP Container Station - Network settings]

Answer (score 1):

Bridge is like combining two interfaces.

so we need to have two Interfaces in creating a bridge.

First Interface : You need  to have a default interface which goes to the Internet on Base Machine.

Now, if you install docker/lxd daemons on Base machine. They will create another Interface.

Now we have Second Interface also.

Now docker/lxd daemons using a utility(may be brctl) and they will create a bridge by attaching/combining that two interfaces.

Docker names it as "docker0", whereas LXD name it as "lxcbr0".

So, they combines those two interfaces and attaches them to a bridge.

"lxcbr0" enables you to launch LXC Containers (System/Fat Containers).
"docker0" enables you to launch docker Containers (Application Containers).

Both are different, You can find it in the below link.

[Difference Between LXC and Docker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254956/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-lxd-and-lxc)

You can run both lxc and docker daemons in one single machine. Then you have both lxcbr0 and docker0 bridges on one single machine. But those two bridges never know that the other bridge really exists or not.

By the End, You cannot attach/assign a same IP Address Range to two different Bridges.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Lxc and docker has been explained here: [LXC oraz Docker® Container](https://qnap.epasystemy.pl/container-station/) - the best explanation in my opinion.

Sorry for code-snippet, but i wasn't able to insert a "html-table-version".

```html
<table class="tab" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="20%"></th>
<th width="40%">LXC</th>
<th width="40%">Docker</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Architecture</td>
<td>Supports full virtualization of the Linux operating system, including startup procedures</td>
<td>A single image and run as an application</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Targets</td>
<td>
<ul>
<li>Run multiple applications in a single VM virtual machine</li>
<li>Requires a fully functional Linux operating system</li>
<li>Requires updating Linux</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td>
<ul>
<li>Single container, single application</li>
<li>Fast deployment and migration between platforms</li>
<li>Running insulated containers in QTS</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Advantages</td>
<td>
<ul>
<li>A light alternative to virtual machines</li>
<li>More flexibility</li>
<li>Data can be saved in the container</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td>
<ul>
<li>Fast and easy deployment</li>
<li>Focus on the application, implementation between machines</li>
<li>Reuse of components</li>
<li>Tool ecosystem</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```